# Pandas isin on many many columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select rows from my dataframe `df` where any of the many columns contains a value that's in a list `my_list`.  There are dozens of columns, and there could be more in the future, so I don't want to iterate over each column in a list.

I *don't* want this:

```
# for loop / iteration
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df[col].isin(my_list), "indicator"] = 1
```

Nor this:

```
# really long indexing
df = df[(df.col1.isin(my_list) | (df.col2.isin(my_list) | (df.col3.isin(my_list) ... (df.col_N.isin(my_list)]  # ad nauseum
```

Nor do I want to reshape the dataframe from a wide to a long format.

I'm thinking (hoping) there's a way to do this in one line, applying the `isin()` to many columns all at once.

Thanks!

## Solution

I ended up using

```
df[df.isin(my_list).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DataFrame.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) which is a DataFrame method and not a string method.

```
new_df = df[df.isin(my_list)]
```

Comment: Nice! Once I added `.any(axis=1)` this worked for me!

`df[df.isin(my_list).any(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 2):

Alternately you may try:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.isin(mylist)).any(axis=1)]
```

OR

```
df[df[df.columns].isin(mylist)]
```

Even you don't need o create a list if not utmost necessary rather directly assign it as follows.

```
df[df[df.columns].isin([3, 12]).any(axis=1)]
```

After checking your efforts:

### Example DataFrame:

```
>>> df
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      1      1     10
1      2      4     12
2      3      7     18
```

### List construct:

```
>>> mylist
[3, 12]
```

### Solutions:

```
>>> df[df.col_1.isin(mylist) | df.col_2.isin(mylist) | df.col_3.isin(mylist)]
   col_1  col_2  col_3
1      2      4     12
2      3      7     18

>>> df[df.isin(mylist).any(axis=1)]
   col_1  col_2  col_3
1      2      4     12
2      3      7     18
```

or :

```
>>> df[df[df.columns].isin(mylist).any(axis=1)]
   col_1  col_2  col_3
1      2      4     12
2      3      7     18
```

Or :

```
>>> df[df.apply(lambda x: x.isin(mylist)).any(axis=1)]
   col_1  col_2  col_3
1      2      4     12
2      3      7     18
```